# Question about a paper on "Aberration and the Speed of Gravity"

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light, causality

I found a paper online by S. Carlip (https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9909087 Aberration and the Speed of Gravity) that looks pretty good, except I can’t get past his metric equation [2.1]! He says it is for the Kinnersley’s “photon rocket”. It appears to be dimensionless. Don’t the Schwarzschild, Kerr, and FLRW metrics have dimensions of length-squared? What am I missing?

The reason Carlip “calculates” the speed of gravity is to refute a paper by Van Flandern who – like Laplace – had argued that observations show gravity must propagate at a speed much greater than c. Carlip shows that a speed of c and rigorous GRT math is consistent with the “observed absence of aberration”. Which is why I am so anxious to understand the math!

Robertson and Noonan, in “Relativity and Cosmology”, 1968, argue that Laplace’s mistake was to assume that the “force” of gravity is what propagates, whereas it is really the “potential”. That doesn’t make a lot of sense for me, so I am interested in Carlip’s demonstration.

Comment: A metric tensors components may have any combination of units in a given coordinate system. If you see the schwarzschild metric tensor, several components are dimensionless while others can be dimensional.

Comment: Ummm Schwarzschild: (cdt)^2, (dr)^2, (r)^2, & (r sin(theta))^2 - all length-squared.

Comment: Yikes, I left out "g=1-2GM/rc^2" above: g(cdt)^2, -(dr^2/g), -(r dtheta)^2, -(r sin(theta)dphi)^2...

Comment: Those are pieces of the line element not the metric tensor itself, the metric tensor components are the coefficients of the terms in the line element, as you can see in your expression g is dimensionless and so for example the $g_{rr}$ term of the tensor is dimensionless as it should so that $g_{rr}dx^r dx^r$ has dimensions of length squared.

Comment: You quote a remark that goes: "Laplace’s mistake was to assume that the *force* of gravity is what propagates, whereas it is really the *potential*." Indeed that that is a most unhelpful remark. I recommend you remove that quote from the question; it makes the question less focused. If you grant galilean relativity then information *can* propagate instantaneously, and it *must*, on pain of violation of conservation laws. I you grant the minkowski metric then effects specific to relativistic physics come into play, as mentioned by Steve Carlip.

Comment: For further discussion see the following pages on the [physics website by Kevin Brown](https://www.mathpages.com/). [Laplace on the speed of gravity](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath690/kmath690.htm) , [Central forces from retarded action](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath566/kmath566.htm). [Trouton-Noble and the Right-Angle Lever](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath651/kmath651.htm). Kevin Brown points out: Max von Laue discussed how forces transform in relativistic context. That connects to how in relativistic mechanics violation of conservation laws does not occur.

Comment: *Don’t the Schwarzschild, Kerr, and FLRW metrics have dimensions of length-squared?* You are conflating *line element* $ds^2$, that has dimension of length squared, and *metric component* $g_{\mu\nu}$.